# Return inside a try and a catch passes when returning empty list but doesn't compile if list is not empty

Tags: java

I had the following code:
import java.util.*;

```
public class InterviewPerp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        something();
    }

    public static List<String> something() {
        String digits = "23";
        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if(Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1)
                //combinations.add("*");
                return combinations;
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return combinations;
        }
        return combinations;
    }
}
```

But when I added an item to baz the compiler said the statement after the try catch is not reachable. I don't understand why. Code below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InterviewPerp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        something();
    }

    public static List<String> something() {
        String digits = "23";
        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if(Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1)
                combinations.add("*");
                return combinations;
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return combinations;
        }
        // Code to calculate combinations
        return combinations;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a MCVE. This isn't one.

Comment: [Your code works for me](https://rextester.com/HOQAXC42015) and I can't reproduce your error.  Though, you could/should move the `return` statement somewhere else.

Comment: Posted the rest of the code.

Comment: "rest of the code" also does not exhibit reported behavior here. build clean. restart your ide. restart your computer. try a different computer.

Comment: Either the code will throw an `NumberFormatException` or it won't. In both cases, you are returning `baz`, that's why the code is unreachable.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat It does not return if no exception and the number is `> 0`. This is probably not the true code that cause the error.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Incorrect. `foo` **could** parse to an `int` that is greater than zero. I can't reproduce the reported compiler error.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss off some of the `{ }` characters or include an extra `;` ?

Comment: Pasted the actual example that doesn't compile on my IDE

Comment: you are missing curly braces here. if(Integer...return combination;
correct it like below..


if(Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1) {
                combinations.add("*");
                return combinations;
}

Comment: Yes, I thought it was probably the `{ }` after the `if` that you'd omitted from the question.  On Stack Overflow, you usually get better answers if you post the code that's causing the problem, not some entirely different piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Either put the code in parenthesis under if like

```
if(Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1)
{
                combinations.add("*");
                return combinations;
}
```

or remove return at the end of method.

Error is because your method has return in both try and catch. Hence the return at the end of method is not reachable.

This last return statement will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the code and comments.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        something();
    }

    public static List<String> something() {
        String digits = "23";
        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1)
                combinations.add("*");
            return combinations; // this code will be executed always if there is no error thus the code after the catch statement will never be reached, generating an error
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return combinations;
        }
        // The code below here will not be executed 
        // Code to calculate combinations
        return combinations; 
    }

}
```

Thus depending on your logic you can add a curly braces to look like this:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1){
    combinations.add("*");
    return combinations;
}
```

Or you can just place all the statements after the `catch` after your `if` statement. Refer below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        something();
    }

    public static List<String> something() {
        String digits = "23";
        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(digits) <= 1)
                combinations.add("*");
            // Code to calculate combinations is transferred here
            return combinations; 
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return combinations;
        }
        // The code below are transferred inside the try block

    }

}
```

But generally just transfer all the codes after the catch block inside the try block for readability purposes. Since adding codes after the catch block may mean or others may read it as that these codes will be executed after the catch block is executed.